# Javascript 2 dimensional array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d

I like to have an array defined in such way in javascript. If someone can help please. Let us say I have academies, and each academies will have an array of values. I believe it is not 2d array requirement.

```
data
[,[]]
[0,[1,2]]
[1,[3,4]]
```

I need to access the data like this.

```
array[0], it should give 1,2 in an array
array[1], it should give 3,4 in an array
```

There is no fixed length defined

```
[a,[b]]
[0,[1,2,3]]
[1,[3,4,5]]
```

I again need to access the data like this.

```
array[0], it should give 1,2,3 in an array
array[1], it should give 3,4,5 in an array
```

Please if someone can help.
Many thanks

Comment: You don't need `0`, `1` because. `0` and `1` are already index of element.

Comment: Since the question isn't too clear, I suggest to add your starting or input data and the expected output from it, maybe with a clear example.

Answer (score 0):

You can define like this

```
var arr = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
arr.map(key=>console.log(key);)// here key itself will be an array..Loop through that to get your individual values.
```

Comment: how do I build this array. Say I have two academies, and their respective data. Can you show me for loops to create this?

Comment: @user3232760 Check this code `let arr = [[0,[1,2]], [1,[3,4]] ];let res = arr.map(x => x[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a 2d array, you could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with each *academy's* number as key and the array as their value. You can use `get` and `set` to retrieve and update the values for a particular key respectively

```js
const map = new Map([
                     [0, [1,2]],
                     [1, [3,4]],
                     [2, [1,2,3]],
                     [3, [3,4,5]]
                    ])

map.set(4, [10,20]) // to add a new value to map

console.log(map.get(1)) // to retrieve value, use "get"
console.log(map.get(3))
```

Or even an object would work:

```js
const obj = {
  0: [1, 2],
  1: [3, 4],
  2: [1, 2, 3],
  3: [3, 4, 5]
}

console.log(obj[0])
console.log(obj[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it in a loop, this some ex. to do it. this code below is to get array month and day.

```js
var month= ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var day= ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
var daycounter = 0;
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {    // 12 for month in 1 year
    arr[month[i]]=[];
    // assump that avery month have 30 day and in 1st jan is sun
    for (var j = 0; j < 30; j++ , daycounter++) {
         daycounter = daycounter % 7;    // this for reset the day name to "sun" again
         arr[month[i]][j]= day[daycounter];
         console.log(arr[month[i]][j]+", "+ (j+1) + " " + month[i]);
    }
}
```

You can improve it according to what you need

Comment: Hi Anastasia and welcome! Do you think you answered the question? If the question is unclear, it is better to wait until it is more accurate.
In my opinion the question was about an array within an array, and I do not see such a case in your answer.